# How to express volume of a sphere as a sum of infinitesimally thick discs?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, spheres

I want to express the volume of a sphere with a radius r as an integral that adds up each infinitesimally thick disc within the volume. So I have dV = A(x) dx, where A(x) is the area of the disc that is at coordinate x. I'm having trouble finding this function in terms of r. Remember, r is the radius of the sphere. At x=0, A = πr^2, and at x=r, A = 0. The bounds of the integral should be -r to r I believe. But what is A(x)?

Comment: Rather $dV = A(x)\,dx.$ $A(x)$ is the AREA of the corresponding cross-section by the plane which is perpendicular to $X$-axis which passes through the point $(x,0,0),$ where $-r \le x \le r.$ Try to show that $A(x)=\pi (r-x)^2.$

Comment: @Olod Yes, of course, my mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
V=\sum \pi (r^{2}-x^{2}) \delta x=\pi \int_{-r}^{r} (r^{2}-x^{2}) dx
\end{eqnarray*}
A little integral calculus & you will recover the well known result. $V_S= \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$.

Comment: So x would be the distance from the origin to the disk. You are integrating $\pi t^2$ where t is the radius of the disk. d, t, and r form a right angled triangle since the perimeter of the disk is part of the sphere.