# Proof of volume of spheres through sum of sections of a sphere

Tags: integration, volume

I know that by integrating the surface area of a sphere we can get the formula of its volume.

Similarly, I wanted to find about other ways of doing this. So, I thought what if we divide the sphere into infinite circles or sections of the sphere and the add their areas for the volume and their perimeter for the surface area.

Problem is I am not able to do this. I tried but didn't work for me. I just knew the above logic but didn't know how to implement it.

So, I would like you to guide me on how I can do this and not just give a direct solution. Also, I would like to know about other ways for getting these results.

P.S.- if you are just giving me the answer can you explain it a bit. My calculus is not very strong. I know basic rules but I don't know how to set up the equations and I think that's where I am weak. How to implement this kind of logic.

Comment: Sorry, it should be this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180670/290189

Comment: Could you explain the answer a bit more?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  My comment is not an answer.  It's not worth my time to repeat someone else's work, despite the possible reputation gain.  Please note that duplicate questions can be closed with five votes from the community.  Duplicate question aside, please elaborate your question a bit more to include your efforts in solving the problem so that it's up to Math.SE's standard.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really is a duplicate of the other question, but only because this question is so unclear at to what you mean. The answer to your question, as asked, is "yes". If you want more, then you need to be clear what it is you are after.

Comment: There you go. I explained it a little.